# Codename One AnalyticsService suddenly completely blocks the application flow

Tags: google-analytics, codenameone

In my codename one application, all the routing is done in a method that looks like that:

```
    if (AnalyticsService.isEnabled()) {
        AnalyticsService.visit(route.toString(), route.getPrevious());
    }

    switch (route) {
        case Home:
            HomeFormManager.getInstance().showForm();
            break;
        case Loading:
            LoadingFormManager.getInstance().showForm();
            break;
        case Error:
            ErrorFormManager.getInstance().showForm();
            break;
        // some other forms here
        default:
            break;
    }
```

The idea is obvious, every time we go to a new form, we register that in the analytics. This code worked flawlessly until today. Now, suddenly the row where we call the `visit` method completely blocks the flow of the application if we are going to the error form. After some debugging, I found that the app gets stuck in AnalyticsService.GetGARequest, and particularly in Log.getUniqueDeviceId, where a request for the device id is sent to codename one build servers and then waits forever for response. This does not happen for other forms since only for the Error form I call Preferences.clearAll() and thus for the other forms Log.getUniqueDeviceId returns directly the id from the preferences. However, I must call Preferences.clearAll() because of the logic in my app. Any idea how to work around this and what recent change caused this?

Comment: It's odd that this would block as the servers should be up. Do you see this in the simulator? If so can you open the network monitor and look at the failed request/response values?

Comment: I just tried it the HTTP request it is not shown in the Network Monitor. Using the debugger, I can see that it hangs in the NetworkManager addToQueueAndWait, and inside it in the run method of the WaitingClass, the field finishedWaiting stays forever false, so maybe this is something related to the EDT and not to the servers?

Comment: Is it possible that the previous request is somehow stuck there or failed in a way that the network manager got into a loop?

Comment: I cannot see that at least. I will try to find a small example that reproduce this, and if I can't, it should be some problem on my side.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, I cannot reproduce this on actual device. Interestingly, I also the CN1 lib for connectivity and it hangs in one very very specific case (different than this one), when Connectivity.isConnected() is called, but also this is not reproduceable on a device, so could be something minor in the simulator.

Comment: I suggest invoking it on a separate thread